# Image is uploaded to the server, but no field is created in the table

Tags: php, mysql

We have it setup to where a user can check a box to signal that the content is mature content. Photos that are uploaded that are not checked are uploaded AND stored in the database, however if they check the box to mark it as adult, it still uploads to the server, but no field is created in the table.

```
$mature=$HTTP_POST_VARS["mature"];
if($mature=="on") {
// $adult=1; // has no function, could be useful?
}
else {
// $adult=0; // has no function, could be useful?

// ALBUM CODE HERE ALBUM CODE HERE ALBUM CODE HERE ALBUM CODE HERE ALBUM CODE HERE 

      $sql="select photo_id as a from user_pics where user_id = $_SESSION[user_id]"; 
      $result2 = mysql_query($sql); 
      $pic=mysql_num_rows($result2); 

      if($pic==0) {
// if no photos found within the database table user_pics

                     // Identify if adult or not.
                     $mature_content=$HTTP_POST_VARS["mature"];
                     if($mature_content=="on") {
                     $adult_rated=1;
                     }
                     else {
                     $adult_rated=0;
                     }
                     // Identify if adult or not.

                    $sql="insert into user_pics";
                    $sql.="(user_id";
                    $sql.=", caption";
                    $sql.=", mature";
                    $sql.=", photo_url";
                    $sql.=", medium_photos";
                    $sql.=", small_photos)";
                    $sql.=" values($_SESSION[user_id]";
                    $sql.=", '$caption'";
                    $sql.=", $adult_rated";     
                    $sql.=", '$picture_url'";       
                    $sql.=", '$med_picture_url'";       
                    $sql.=", '$small_picture_url')";
                    $result=mysql_query($sql);      
                    $photo_id = mysql_insert_id();

      } else {
// if one or more than one photo

                // Identify if adult or not.
                $mature_content=$HTTP_POST_VARS["mature"];
                if($mature_content=="on") {
                $adult_rated=1;
                }
                else {
                $adult_rated=0;
                }
                // Identify if adult or not.

                $sql="insert into user_pics";
                $sql.="(user_id";
                $sql.=", caption";
                $sql.=", mature";
                $sql.=", photo_url";
                $sql.=", medium_photos";
                $sql.=", small_photos)";
                $sql.=" values($_SESSION[user_id]";
                $sql.=", '$caption'";
                $sql.=", $adult_rated";     
                $sql.=", '$picture_url'";       
                $sql.=", '$med_picture_url'";       
                $sql.=", '$small_picture_url')";
                $result=mysql_query($sql);      
                $photo_id = mysql_insert_id();
      } 
// ALBUM CODE HERE ALBUM CODE HERE ALBUM CODE HERE ALBUM CODE HERE ALBUM CODE HERE 
}
```

Comment: Why do you have that query repeated twice? I think it would be more succinct if you had one copy, and just changed the thing that is different between them.

Answer (score 0):

If `$mature=="on"` then you are skipping the entire block of code that might insert something into the database. So nothing will get inserted if that is true. Unless I am misunderstanding what you  are asking.